# Log4net - how to log calling method name in WCF

Tags: singleton, log4net, wrapper

I have written a Singleton wrapper for log4net and it will be called across all layers of my WCF service. I am unable to log calling method name. Pls suggest if any inputs from my below code. Thanks.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Imports log4net
Imports System.Reflection
```

```
Public Class Logger
Implements ILog

Private Shared m_instance As Logger
Private Shared log As log4net.ILog = Nothing

Public Sub New()
    If log Is Nothing Then
        'log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType) ' -> This always logs 'Logger'
        log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), "MyLogger")  ' -> This always logs 'MyLogger'
    End If

End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Write() As Logger
    Get
        m_instance = New Logger()
        Return m_instance
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Debug(msg As String) Implements ILog.Debug
    log.Debug(msg)
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''  

Public Interface ILog
     Sub Debug(msg As String)
End Interface
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

---

I have made it more simple as below to log method name. But I have to pass classname as parameter. Pls suggest is this acceptable design?

```
''''' Calling code ''''''''''''''''''''
Logger(of MyClassName).Debug("message")


''''''Log4net wrapper'''''''''''''''''''''
Imports log4net
Imports System.Reflection
```

```
Public NotInheritable Class Logger(Of T)

Private Shared log As log4net.ILog = Nothing

Private Shared ReadOnly Property LogProvider() As log4net.ILog
    Get
        If (log Is Nothing) Then
            Dim CallingMethod As String = GetType(T).ToString() & "." & (New StackTrace()).GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name
            log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(CallingMethod)
        End If
        Return log
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Sub Debug(msg As String)
    LogProvider.Debug(msg)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A logging instance can only have one name, you can't change it. If you want to use a diffrent name in each method you need to make a logger for ech method.

```
    log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType) ' -> This always logs 'Logger'
    log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name) ' -> This gives you the name of the current method
    log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), "MyLogger")  ' -> This always logs 'MyLogger'
```

Creating the logger inside your method like:

```
    ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name) ' -> This gives you the name of the current method
```

You will have a logger with the name of the method, I would add the name of the class either:

```
    ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name) ' -> This gives you the name of the current method
```